# Mobile wallets for test eth?

Tags: wallets, testnets

Can anyone suggest mobile wallets (both IOS and Andriod) that supports testnet Eth? Jaxx used to (or at least the IOS version used to), but doesn't look as though it does now.

Answer (score 2):

Coinbase Wallet on iOS and Android (https://wallet.coinbase.com/) 
Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Active Network
Supports Kovan, Rinkeby and Ropsten

Status.im on iOS and Android (https://status.im/get/)
Profile -> Advanced -> Development mode (toggle) then change Network in same menu
Supports Rinkeby and Ropsten

Walleth on Android (https://walleth.org/)
I don't have an Android next to me so can't confirm how to get to testnets

Comment: Tried Coinbase Wallet and it worked on my iPhone. Thanks very much for the detailed information - I had tried a number of wallets with no luck!